# React-redux tutorial - stuck trying to learn redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to redux and decided to watch some tutorials on youtube.  Here is my Repo for what I have so far: [repo](https://github.com/tmontobbio/redux-2023)

When I try to destructure the function "login" (located: src/components/features/user.js) and export it I get an error in the chrome dev tools:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'login' of 'userslice.reducers' as it is undefined."

I've searched the web for answers but the things I found are much more complicated than my example project and I'm not sure what to make of it.  I'm new to this as well as a new developer, any insight would be appreciated!

Tutorial video @ timestamp: [tutorial](https://youtu.be/ncfO0XHWwzQ?t=418)

```
//src/components/features/user.js

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const userslice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: { name: "", email: "", age: "" },
    reducers: {
        // login is the function, state = initialState, action includes payload
        login: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const { login } = userslice.reducers
export default userslice.actions
```

Tried to change variable names such as userslice to userSlice and got more errors.

Tried exporting "login" as the default export and got more errors.

Comment: Does `userslice` return the object passed to it? Double-check what it is

Comment: as in add the return keyword after the declaration but before the actual slice object?

Comment: Check what `userslice` is